# Python butterworth Filter scipy

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, scipy, butterworth

i have sample csv files, one is with unfiltered data and the other one is filtered with butterworth filter from the Software where the csv comes from. I wanna filter the unfiltered data myself and then compare the results. I use the butter Filter from scipy. I plot both data but the results from the scipy butter filter are a little bit different then the filtered data from the original Software. On an first look it seems good but when you zoom in there are small differences.

The filtered data is filtered with CFC180. Perhaps someone can help me what is going wrong? Thanks!

Col0 = Time, Col1 = X-Axle. I only use col0 and col1, so ignore the others.

Sample rate from Software is 20000Hz. There is an field with Hardware AA Filter (-3db) and the value for this is 4000 for col1 if this is relevant.

Here is my python code so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

c_data = {}
xmin = -5.00005
xmax = 5
c_filt = 'black'
g = 9.81

# Butterworth Filter
cfc60 = signal.butter(4, 100, output='sos', fs=20000)
cfc180 = signal.butter(4, 300, output='sos', fs=20000)
cfc600 = signal.butter(4, 1000, output='sos', fs=20000)
cfc1000 = signal.butter(4, 1650, output='sos', fs=20000)


def Acceleration(Axis_name, Axis_data, ymin, ymax, nofilter=False):

    if nofilter is True:
        print("Filtered from Software", Axis_data)
        plt.plot(
            c_data["t"], Axis_data/g, c_filt,
            label=f"{Axis_name}"
        )
    else:
        # CFC180
        Axis_data_filtered = signal.sosfilt(cfc180, Axis_data)
        print("Filtered scipy butter", Axis_data_filtered)
        plt.plot(
            c_data["t"], Axis_data_filtered/g, c_filt,
            label=f"{Axis_name}"
        )

    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    plt.grid(True)

    plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
    plt.tick_params(which='minor', width=1, length=3, color='black')
    plt.minorticks_on()

    plt.xlabel("time [s]")
    plt.ylabel(f"{Axis_name} axle")
    plt.show(block=True)


def GetData(File, filtering=False):

    dataframe = pd.read_csv(File, sep=';', skiprows=0, header=None)
    dfvalues = dataframe.values
    c_data["t"] = dfvalues[:, 0]  # time
    c_data["x_acc"] = dfvalues[:, 1]  # x axle
    Acceleration('X', c_data["x_acc"], -25, 20, filtering)
    return


GetData("unfiltered.csv", False)
# GetData("filtered.csv", True)
```

So i have it on pastebin the two sample csv data.
[Unfiltered Data](https://pastebin.com/1PnqfFCU)
[Filtered Data](https://pastebin.com/aZgeNxRz)

Comment: The shape of the curve is correct, there's just a bit of a time offset.  That can happen with filters.  Do you know the exact parameters used by the software?

Comment: This is what i have
    Sample Rate (Hz) 20000
    Hardware AA Filter (-3dB) 4000
    Software Filter (-3dB) NONE
    Number of Pre-Zero Data Pts 100001
    Number of Post-Zero Data Pts 100001
    Data Zero (CNTS) -77
    Scale Factor (EU/CNT) -0,127247789
    Scale Factor (mV/CNT) -0,009548688

Comment: So why do you think you need a lowpass filter at 300Hz?

Comment: Have it from other forum, thought that cfc180 is always same, 300hz, low. Only with sample rate change. So it isnt? :-) Is CFC180, CFC60, CFC600 not normed?

Comment: Your `cfc180` is, indeed, a 300Hz low-pass filter, assuming the data is 20kHz.  The cutoff value is in the same units as `fs`.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand. When i read your comment you mean my filtering is wrong right?

Comment: No, I don't have enough information to know what the other software is doing.  If you need a 300Hz low-pass filter, then that's what you have in `cfc180`, but the delays might be different.  If the curve shapes are the same, then you have what you need.